# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}[x^2+(1+2\sqrt{2})x+1][1-x+x^2-x^3+...+x^{50}]}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

My brother's friend gave me the following wicked integral with a beautiful result

> \begin{equation}
> {\Large\int_0^\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x} \bigg[x^2+\left(1+2\sqrt{2}\right)x+1\bigg] \bigg[1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots+x^{50}\bigg]}={\large\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)\pi}
> \end{equation}

He claimed the above integral can be generalised to the following form
\begin{equation}
{\Large\int_0^\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x} \bigg[x^2+ax+1\bigg] \bigg[1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots+(-x)^{n}\bigg]}=\ldots
\end{equation}
This is a challenging problem. How to prove it and what is the closed-form of the general integral?

Comment: Is your brother's friend named Cleo?

Comment: Let $x=-y$, then $1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots+x^{50}=1+y+y^2+y^3+\cdots+y^{50}=\frac{1-y^{51}}{1-y}$

Comment: Mr. @GitGud I wish he were Cleo, but Ms. Cleo is a she, lol

Comment: Hint: 1) substitute $x$ by $1/x$ and combine the new integral with the old to get rid of the horrible factor at end 2) change variable to $u = \sqrt{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: @mike You're on the right track, *go on!*

Comment: Mr. @achillehui You're on the right track too! Yeah, it's not just too easy for her, but for you too. Please cracking for the general form too (ô‿ô)

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova actually I have derived the final expression. The two hint is enough for you to derive the answer yourself. It is pretty simple and I'm waiting you to answer your own question. ;-p

Comment: Mr. @achillehui I'm interested in knowing the closed-form of the general term. I'll will answer it if no-one does but not now since it's already past midnight here, so is HK right? Nightly night, CYA! ≥Ö‿Ö≤

Comment: I find it remarkable, in the original formula, that the sum is supposed to stop at $x^50$ and yet the result is so simple.

Comment: Has anyone checked to see whether Mathematica or Yacas can solve this analytically? (just wondering)

Comment: Does the $+x^n$ in the general form mean that $n$ has to be even?  Or could it be a minus?

Comment: It's a special case of the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \left(\frac{x}{x^{2}+2ax+1} \right)^{r} \frac{x+1}{x(x^{s}+1)} \ dx = \frac{B(r - \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})}{2^{r-1/2} (1+a)^{r-1/2}} . $$ There is an entire chapter in the book Irresistible Integrals devoted to this integral.

Comment: @RandomVariable Wow! I've never known there is a general form other than I posted. Could you please post your solution Mr. RV? I really want to know how one gets that closed-form. Thank you...

Comment: http://129.81.170.14/~vhm/papers_html/3param.pdf It's the same integral but written in a slightly different form.

Comment: @RandomVariable Thanks for the link of paper. I really love it! BTW, in your opinion, is Irresistible Integrals a good book? If so, maybe I'll purchase it at Amazon

Comment: It's a good book, but not so good that I would necessarily recommend buying it. That paper covers the most interesting chapter in the book.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Indeed let
$$
I(n,a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}(1+ax+x^2)(\sum_{k=0}^n(-x)^k)}
$$
The change of variables $x\leftarrow 1/x$ yields
$$
I(n,a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}dx}{ \sqrt{x}(1+ax+x^2)(\sum_{k=0}^n(-x)^k)}
$$
Thus
$$
2I(n,a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{1+x}{\sqrt{x}(1+ax+x^2)}dx=
2\int_0^\infty\frac{1+t^2}{ 1+at^2+t^4}dt
$$
Or equivalently, setting $u=t-1/t$,
$$
I(n,a)=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{du}{ 2+a+u^2} =\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2+a}}.
$$

Comment: I think it is very unintuitive that this is independent of $n$. It would be nice if someone offered an intuitive explanation of that fact.

Comment: Nice answer. It's all true if $n \geq 0$ and $a > -2$.

Comment: Very nice answer Prof! ٩(˘◡˘)۶